# Actionmailer - heroku app

Tags: ruby, heroku, actionmailer

This is a newbie question so please excuse me, I have been working with rails, but this is the first time i am trying to require gems from a heroku app that does not include rails - just a plain Ruby app.
ok I have a app.rb file looking like this:

```
require "sinatra"
require 'koala'
require 'action_mailer'
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address   => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
   :port      => 587,
   :domain    => "MYDOMAIN",
   :authentication => :plain,
   :user_name      => "USER_NAME",
   :password       => "PASSWORD",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
ActionMailer::Base.view_paths= File.dirname(__FILE__)

class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "MY_EMAIL"

  def welcome_email
    mail(:to => "MY_EMAIL", :subject => "Test mail", :body => "Test mail body")
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is run

```
TestMailer::deliver_test_email
```

in the console and get the details or run

```
TestMailer::deliver_test_email.deliver
```

to send a test email

but all i get is :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::TestMailer
```

I have included actionmailer in the Gemfile and its also in the Gemfile.lock

I am sure it is something straight forward for an experienced Ruby dev, but I am struggling could anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What console are you running this from? Have you loaded app.rb ? You also need to require 'bundler/setup' for your gemfile to actually be used.

Comment: Thanks Fredrick for your response. Yes I had app.rb loaded and I was running it in the console (not irb) I run some checks to see what was required and I ended up using Mail instead which seemed to work more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of testing and research I ended up using Mail instead, this was my final code which when run works fine, I hope it helps anyone who is having the same issues as I was :)

```
require 'mail'

Mail.defaults do

  delivery_method :smtp, { :address   => "smtp.sendgrid.net",

                           :port      => 587,
                           :domain    => "MY_DOMAIN",
                           :user_name => "USER_NAME",
                           :password  => "PASSWORD",
                           :authentication => 'plain',
                           :enable_starttls_auto => true }
end

mail = Mail.deliver do
  to 'EMAIL'
  from 'Your Name <NAME@MY_DOMAIN>'
  subject 'This is the subject of your email'
  text_part do
    body 'hello world in text'
  end
  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body '<b>hello world in HTML</b>'
  end
end
```